# C++: Accessing class properties in header implementation file

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the doubly linkedlist data structure, so I created a class that has a private property `node` of type `Node`, when I try to access this property from a function implementation using `this` keyword the application fails. I need help

Header file for LinkedList.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<class T>
class LinkedList{
    private :
    struct Node{
        T value;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
    }node;
    public :
        LinkedList();
        LinkedList(T item);
        void add(T item);
//        void get();
//        void insert();
//        void remove();
};
```

Below is the implementation of the header file.

```
#include "LinkedList.hpp"

template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){

}


template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T item){

}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(T item){
    Node* node = new Node;
    node->value = item;
    node->prev = NULL;

    //Where the error is being generated
    node->next = this.node;

};
```

The error returned says:

```
/Users/mac/Documents/LinkedList/LinkedList/LinkedList.cpp:27:22: Member reference base type 'LinkedList<T> *' is not a structure or union
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, as pointed out by the error message.

Use:

```
this->node
```

Comment: It works when I do this: `node->next = &this->node;`, why it works is what I do not understand

Comment: `&this->node` is equivalent to `&(this->node)`. `this` is a pointer. `this->node` is a `struct Node` and finally `&this->node` is an address of that `struct` (or a pointer to it), which is what you need.

Comment: Also your implementation is broken. Unless you modify `add()`, you won't be able to implement `get()`, as the list's element will always be the last one. Traditionally, the list class should only contain a pointer to `struct Node` and that should be the first one in the list. Also traditionally, `add()` adds an element to the end of the list.